# In c++ when we create a class without extending to any class

Tags: c++

In c++ when we create a class without extending to any class.

1. Whether it doesn't have any parent class?
2. If yes then for which class we are overriding the operators?

Comment: A class with no parent extends no class. It is its own distinct type. Some default operators can or will be created by the compiler automatically, but they are not inherited.

Comment: I've read your question several times and have no idea what you are asking. Please clarify.

Comment: Instead of adding them in each and every class by compiler.we can declare default items in one class and making this class parent by compiler is a good option right.

Answer (score 2):

A class without base classes is just that : a type on its own.
As such, there is nothing to override from any base class, neither operators nor anything else.

Comment: is it so,along with default constructor ,copy constructor, a copy assignment operator destructor the default operators and any other required will be added by compiler

Comment: @krishnakanthreddy Yes, the compiler can generate default implementations of the special member functions. But there is no overriding, for there is no parent implementation to override.